# Error with Between clause

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm getting the following error with this query:  Between operator without And in query expression '[DateTime] BETWEEN [StartDate'.

The query and database is in Access 2010

Thank in advance for your help!

```
SELECT 
    t1.[Name], 
    Max(t1.[Sum3Areas]) AS [Max]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        qryUnion.[Name]
        , Year(qryUnion.[Date]) as dtYear
        , DatePart("ww",[Date]) + IIF(Weekday([Date]) >= 6,1,0) as dtWeek
        , SUM(qryUnion.[Amount]) as Sum3Areas 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            1 as Source, 
            EID As [Name],  
            Closed     As [Amount], 
            DateTime As [Date] 
        FROM IssueTrakINNER 
        JOIN [DateRangeCriteria] 
            ON [DateTime] BETWEEN [StartDate] and [EndDate] 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT 
            2 as Source, 
            EID AS [Name], 
            Completed As [Amount], 
            DateCompleted AS enter code here[Date] 
        FROM Kana 
        INNER JOIN [DateRangeCriteria] 
            ON [DateTime] BETWEEN [StartDate] and [EndDate] 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT 
            3 as Source, 
            EID AS [Name], 
            Handled As [Amount], 
            DateTime AS [Date] 
        FROM Chat 
        INNER JOIN [DateRangeCriteria] 
            ON [DateTime] BETWEEN [StartDate] and [EndDate]
    ) 
    as qryUnion 
    GROUP BY qryUnion.[Name] , Year(qryUnion.[Date]), DatePart("ww",[Date]) + IIF(Weekday([Date]) >= 6,1,0)
) AS t1 GROUP BY t1.[Name]
```

Comment: Are you trying to edit sql code that Access generated? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `BETWEEN` operator in your `JOIN`...`ON` statement, use it in the `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
select
    ...
from tableA
join tableB
    on tableA.[DateTime] = tableB.[DateTime]
where tableA.[DateTime] BETWEEN #mm/dd/yyyy# AND #mm/dd/yyyy#
```